# What must be corrected in this regex to extract pronunciation from the indonesian sentence?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation

in English pronunciation for the word **ability** is pronounced 4 syllables:
**a, bi, li, ty**

in Indonesian pronunciation for the word **kekuatan** is pronounced 4 syllables:
**ke, ku, a, tan**

This is rules:

[image]

This is a sample sentence from indonesia

```
Saya akan menyambutnya di kampung. Kita saling menyayangi untuk minum air teh. menganggap menggertak minggu mencinta
```

I have written regex like this https://regex101.com/r/At64WO/3

```
[^aeiou]*[aeiou]+(?:[^aeiou]*$|[^aeiou](?=[^aeiou]))?
```

and result

Sa|ya| a|kan| men|**yam**|but|nya |di |kam|**pun**|g. Ki|ta |sa|**lin**|g men|**ya**|yan|**gi**| un|tuk mi|num| **air**| teh.|men|**gan**|ggap| men|**gger**|tak |min|**ggu** |men|cin|ta

I want results become (bold marked)

Sa|ya| a|kan| me|**nyam**|but|nya |di |kam|**pung.** |Ki|ta |sa|**ling** |me|**nya**|ya|**ngi**| un|tuk mi|num| **a**|**ir**| teh. |me|**ngang**|gap| meng|**ger**|tak |ming|**gu** |men|cin|ta

if there is not yet understood from the question please comment

Comment: Your question is too unclear. What are the rules? What is a voice word?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, voice word I mean is **pronunciation** forgive me for my mistakes. I have fixed my question

Comment: What you describe as "times" are **syllables**. `ability` word contains 4 syllables. Now, what kind of matches do you expect? Those that start with .... and contain.... and end in... ? Fill in the gaps.

Comment: Yes, it is syllables. I have added the image as a rule to make it clearer.

Comment: Ok, you want to split all words into syllables.

Comment: Yes, that is true. to Syllables (Pronunciation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to split words into syllables, and syllables start with a consonant sequence and then end in a vowel.

Vowel pattern: `a(?:[iu](?!(?:${consonant})+\b))?|o(?:i(?!(?:${consonant})+\b))?|[aeiou]`
Consonant pattern: `kh|n[yg]|sy|[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]`

The regex scheme for a syllable is `(?:${consonant})*(?:${vowel})(?:(?:${consonant})*(?=[^a-zA-Z]|$)|(?>${consonant})(?=(?:${consonant})))?`, **but** JS regex does not support atomic groups (see `(?>${consonant})`). So, you need to emulate it using a positive lookahead with a capturing group and a backreference after it (`(?=(${consonant}))\1`).

Here is the JS demo:

```js
const text = 'Saya akan menyambutnya di kampung. Kita saling menyayangi untuk minum air teh. menganggap menggertak minggu mencinta';
const consonant = 'kh|n[yg]|sy|[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]';
const vowel = `a(?:[iu](?!(?:${consonant})+\\b))?|o(?:i(?!(?:${consonant})+\\b))?|[aeiou]`;
const regex = new RegExp(`(?:${consonant})*(?:${vowel})(?:(?:${consonant})*(?=[^a-zA-Z]|$)|(?=(${consonant}))\\1(?=(?:${consonant})))?`, 'gi');
console.log(text.match(regex));
```

The regex is

```
/(?:kh|n[yg]|sy|[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])*(?:a(?:[iu](?!(?:kh|n[yg]|sy|[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])+\b))?|o(?:i(?!(?:kh|n[yg]|sy|[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])+\b))?|[aeiou])(?:(?:kh|n[yg]|sy|[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])*(?=[^a-zA-Z]|$)|(?=(kh|n[yg]|sy|[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]))\1(?=kh|n[yg]|sy|[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]))?/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mi5yRL/6).

Comment: Result in the sample everything is right except
the noun of: `air` should be separated to `a,ir`

Comment: @HediHerdiana I removed `+` after `(?:${vowel})`, it seems it was redundant. However, `air` seems correct, because you say `ai` is considered a single vowel. Else, consider using `(?:au|oi|[aeiou])` for vowel pattern. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mi5yRL/4).

Comment: There are two conditions for example:

`air` become `a,ir`
`pandai` become `pan,dai`

Comment: `aila` become `ai,la`
`pandai` become `pan,dai` not `pan,da,i`

Comment: Please check [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mi5yRL/5), and this one for [JS](https://regex101.com/r/Mi5yRL/6)

Comment: in javascript console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Octal escape sequences are not allowed in template strings.

Comment: @HediHerdiana You need to use ``\\1``  in the code, not ``\1`` because it is a regular template literal. I updated the solution in the answer.

Comment: `air` still not correct please check https://jsfiddle.net/aahedi/2vyb40g3/1/

Comment: @HediHerdiana No, check my updated answer. You should have used word boundaries, `"\\b"`, not backspace sequences `"\b"`.

Comment: I have marked it as the correct answer, thank you very much for all your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

Malay/Indonesian syllabification turns out to be a fairly complicated subject. A bit of googling led me down a rabbit hole of corner cases. This answer will mostly be talking about the Malay language because that's what I'm familiar with but I strongly suspect it can be applied to Indonesian as well (barring some weird Javanese loan words, but Javanese also tend to follow the same rules).

Linguists tend to group Malay syllables int 4 structures:

1. CV
2. VC
3. CVC
4. V

So it would seem that your regexp should suffice. Note however that linguists group the special sound `ng` as one letter (see this paper as an example: https://www.academia.edu/3001402). So when you see a syllable described as `CVC` do note that it includes sounds like `peng` or `meng`. I don't know of any 3 letter syllable in Malay that contains `ng` but I know some Indonesian words that start with `ngo` and end with `ong` so let's add that for to our list.

Given the special treatment of `ng` we can add to the list of syllable structure:

1. Cg?V
2. VCg?
3. CVCg?
4. V

Given that we want to match the 4 letter group `CVCg?` if possible instead of just `VCg?` I'd reorder the matching order to:

1. CVCg?
2. VCg?
3. Cg?V
4. V

If you OR them together you'd get a regexp:

```
[^aeiou][aeiou][^aeiou]g?|[aeiou][^aeiou]g?|[^aeiou]g?[aeiou]|[aeiou]
```

Yes, this regexp is quite long and can probably be simplified (for example, the first two groups can probably be written as `[^aeiou]?[aeiou][^aeiou]g?`) but this is probably easier to reason about and understand.

---

**Addendum**

Wiktor's answer reminds me that there is another sound that's special: `nya`. So the pattern can be improved with:

1. CVC[gy]?
2. VC[gy]?
3. C[gy]?V
4. V

which gives:

```
[^aeiou][aeiou][^aeiou][gy]?|[aeiou][^aeiou][gy]?|[^aeiou][gy]?[aeiou]|[aeiou]
```

Which does indeed produce better syllabification. But I think Wiktor's regexp generates even better results.